# Align Righthand Side Comments

Tags: comments, alignment

I have a bunch of assembly code that needs commenting and I want to avoid having to space forward to make a comment every time just to align the comments.

```
movq %rdi, %rdi      # comment
jne label            # comment
addl %esi, %esi      # comment
```

Is there an easy way to do this with vanilla vim? Note the differing line lengths.

Comment: What behavior do you want? Do you want it to do this automatically as you type? Do you want to be able to run a command in normal mode after you're done typing?

Comment: I'm not really too concerned about replicating the behaviour - I just want to know how I would achieve it to better understand vim and prevent similar repetition from occurring in the future.

Comment: More solutions here that give a good overview of the different approaches in Vim: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1229900/reformat-in-vim-for-a-nice-column-layout

Answer (score 1):

I think this will accomplish what you want. During typing, press `<F1>` to pad spaces to the 21st column as shown. You can add `#␣` to either of these mappings to have the comment started automatically. Note that this will erase any existing comment.

```
nnoremap <F1> 21A <Esc>d21\|
imap <F1> <Esc><F1>a
```

The trick is taken from this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12412493/365478